# How to extract all the strings present in an activity of Android app

Tags: java, android, appium

I have an android app which is going to be translated in different languages, and I need to test that. I need to go to each activity in that app and verify whether all strings are actually translated to the selected language. Instead of manually testing this, I am planning to automate.

Is there anyway to extract all the strings present in the Android activity using Appium?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?  If you want to test that the correct string is on screen in each language, I think that's a waste of time-  you're retesting Android's locale system.  If you're testing that each string is different in each language that's wrong- for example "No" is "No" in english and spanish.

Comment: If you want to test that every string in strings.xml is also in each locale specific strings.xml that's closer-  but you would test that with a script on the build machine, not a unit test.  ALso some strings won't be translated and should only be in the main strings file-  for example your app's name is generally not translated.

Comment: @GabeSechan, we don't use any automated translation system. Language experts will give us the translations for all the strings to the developers. Developers will implement that and provide the build to us, QAs. We need to just check that whether all strings in all pages are translated to the selected language(by just checking whether it is not in English).

Comment: Of course-  nobody does automated translations, they're shit.  Doesn't change anything I said-  testing on each screen in each language is really testing the wrong thing-  you're testing the locale system on Android by doing that, and forcing N runs through every screen of your app in every language.  Highly inefficient.  A better way would be to write a script that checks that any string in strings.xml is also in all of the other values-xx/strings.xml, except for those strings that aren't meant to be translated.

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak about Appium but ....

Android studio will highlight with a warning any strings in your main `res/values/strings.xml` that are not present in `res/values-country-code/strings.xml`